# Digital Ocean / Nginx / MySQL / MVC deployment

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, nginx, deployment, digital-ocean

I am trying to deploy and host a website through a Digital Ocean droplet using Nginx, MySQL and dotnet-core. I was able to get the entire project over to the Digital Ocean droplet, but now I am having trouble updating the databases and get "An error occurred using the connection to database '' on server 'localhost'" & 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'. I believe I didn't transfer over the user secrets correctly but I'm honestly not sure. I transfered the entire project via GIT so I had to manually add all connection strings with the command 'dotnet user-secrets set "SecretKey" "SecretValue"'. I've already installed dotnet-core, MySQL, Nginx and all that good stuff on my digital ocean droplet.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve my problem, I am taking a slightly different approach.

I am using the F1 (free tier) Azure app service to actually host the website. I am however still going to use my Digital Ocean droplet to host my database. I am then going to use Cloudflare to point my nameservers to. That was I can use my personal domain for the website instead of using the Azure App service domain. I know this isn't really an 'answer', but it provides an easier path to accomplish my goal. Thank you for everyone's insight!

Answer (score 0):

`'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'` - I had the same issue on a Linux VM. In my case the database user had access denied while connecting to the database.

Check if the database user account that you are using to connect to the `Mysql` database has proper access rights set. Connect to the mysql database from shell and run the following query:

```
select user, host from mysql.user;
```

The output would be something like this:

```
+----------+-----------+
| user     | host      |
+----------+-----------+
| cron     | %         |
| custom   | %         |
| abc      | %         |
| slave    | %         |
| root     | 127.0.0.1 |
| root     | ::1       |
|          | localhost |
| cron     | localhost |
| abcuser  | localhost |
| root     | localhost |
|          | aaaaabox  |
| root     | aaaaabox  |
+----------+-----------+
```

As you can see the `root` has access right on *localhost, ::1, 127.0.0.1*. Which are all local domains.

In your case if any of those are missing then use the following command to add the missing ones:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DBNAME.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

Where `DBNAME` is the name of your Database, `root` is the DB user name, `localhost` is the domain.

**Please note:** You should not be connecting to the mysql database with the `root` account. You can create a separate account that will have access right limited to the application database only.

Here is how you can create a new database user account and connect to the database from your application:

```
CREATE USER 'appuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'appuserpass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DBNAME.* TO 'appuser'@'localhost';

GRANT ALL ON DBNAME.* TO 'appuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'appuserpass';
GRANT ALL ON DBNAME.* TO 'appuser'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'appuserpass';
GRANT ALL ON DBNAME.* TO 'appuser'@'::1' IDENTIFIED BY 'appuserpass';
```

Here is the connection string:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "server=127.0.0.1;user=appuser;password=appuserpass;port=3306;database=DBNAME;"
  },
```

**Update:**

If you are trying to connect to a MySql database from outside the machine then you need to make sure:

- MySql DB is setup to allow remote connection. For that you can follow the tutorial here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-mysql
- Make sure there is no issue with the Firewall. i.e. Firewall is not blocking the port you are using to connect to the MySql DB. Followe the firewall configuration [here](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/mysql/how-to-grant-remote-access-mysql-vps)

**Do not forget** to turn the remote access off when you are done debugging. Otherwise this will create additional security conserns.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is all very new material for me so I'm requesting your patience haha At the moment I am simply trying to connect my local MVC project to the DO droplet server. I'm using code first migrations with EF Core so from my understanding I shouldn't need the droplet databases created yet.... right? I have my connection strings with the server=droplet_ip. When I attempt to update my database I receieve the error `Host 'my_local_ip' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server`.

Comment: @AndrewSmith The solution provided was to address the issue when the app is running with the same machine where the mysql databaser server is running. If you are running a local MVC project then another issue we have to address; which is mysql remote connection. I have updated the answer.